# Finding $n$ in $n=ReverseFactorial(x)$ where $x$ is known.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, factorial

My software application receives a series of very large integers (hundreds of decimal digits). So far, I have been using string/textual representation of decimal digits for very simple manipulation (calculating on the number of digits, etc.).

I want to find the highest $n$ in $n=ReverseFactorial(x)$ where $x$ is the big integer I already have. Examples of expected results would be:

- $4=ReverseFactorial(24)$
- $4=ReverseFactorial(25)$
- $4=ReverseFactorial(119)$
- $5=ReverseFactorial(120)$
- $5=ReverseFactorial(719)$
- $6=ReverseFactorial(720)$

I can convert $x$ into its respective decimal or binary notation if either of those number systems could help in calculating $n$ very fast. As an example, finding the base 2 log for a very large number is possible by inspecting the most significant bit. Is there such a solution for factorials? Could the number of digits provide a clue?

**UPDATE:** Based on [ShreevatsaR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2652588/938668), it appears that if the number to be tested is not an exact factorial (which it is not in my case), there is no efficient way to determine $n$. I wanted to verify this here so I can move on to other ways of addressing my context.

Comment: @Amzoti: Ouch. I can see what you mean. My case is closer to $101!-100!$. But instead of performing the actual calculation, I wonder if there is some logarithmic scale where I can approximate which two values of $n$ a given number falls between.

Comment: See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=101%21-100%21 (it is 160-decimal-digits!). Compare to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma%5B101%5D-Gamma%5B100%5D and http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma%5B102%5D-Gamma%5B100%5D, maybe consider the approach by Andrew on the link

Comment: [This](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12828/inverse-gamma-function) mathoverflow question seems relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $n! \approx \left(\frac ne \right)^n\sqrt {2\pi n}, \log n! \approx n(\log n -1)+1.838 +\frac 12 \log n$ and iteration:  start with $n_0=\log x,$ then $n_1=\frac {\log x}{\log n_0}$ will bracket the root.  Use you favorite root finder, which should converge quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a problem even if the number is not an exact factorial.

Here is how to solve the problem:

by definition: $$ n! = n \times (n-1) \times ..... \times 2 \times 1$$

here is how to get n if you have x:

start by dividing by 2, there are three cases:

1. we get a number greater than 1, in this case keep dividing by
   3,4,5... until you reach something smaller than or equal 1. see the
   two cases below:

   2.we get exactly 1, this is what we want, in this case the last number we divided by is n.

   1. we get something less than 1, in this case we have to get back one step i.e n = last number we divided by - 1.

## example:

let us take the number 719, start by dividing by 2:

$\frac{719}{2} = 359.5$ --> still greater than 1
$\frac{395.5}{3} = 119.83$ --> still greater than 1
$\frac{119.83}{4} = 29.9575$ --> still greater than 1
$\frac{29.9575}{5} = 5.9915$ --> still greater than 1
$\frac{5.9915}{6} = 0.998$  --> less than 1
we should get back to the previous number i.e n=5.

Here is a simple function in c to do this:

```
  long reverse(unsigned long long x)
{
long i;
double n;
n=x;
for(i=2; n>1;i++)
   {
    n= n/i;

    if(n == 1)
    return i;
    else if(n < 1)

        return i-1;


   }
 }
```